# Can't pass `params` directly into rmarkdown::render()

Tags: r, r-markdown

After reading about parameterized reports [in R markdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html), I tried to implement them myself. Creating a simple Rmarkdown example named "work_formatting.Rmd", I added some parameters.

````
---
title: "`r params$doc_title`"
author: "Paul M. Hargarten"
---
 

Date Generated: `r params$date`

# Header 1

Blah blah blah text

```{r cars}
cat("For site ", params$site_number, "\n")
summary(cars)
```
````

And then tried to render it

```
number <- c(100, 200, 300)
for(i in 1:3){
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "work_formatting.Rmd",
  output_file = paste0("word_formatting_", number[i], ".docx"), 
  output_format = my_word(),
  params =list(
      doc_title = paste("Some_title"),
      date = lubridate::today(),
      site_number = number[i]
  ),
  clean = TRUE,
  quiet = FALSE
)
}
```

but I received this error

```
processing file: work_formatting.Rmd
  |..................                                                                                                                             |  12%
   inline R code fragments
Quitting from lines 2-8 (work_formatting.Rmd) 
Error in eval(parse_only(code), envir = envir) : 
  object 'params' not found
```

If I define `params` first (i.e., see below), the word documents are created as expected. I think that this solution works because the default environment used by `render()` is `parent.frame()` and thus can find the global object `params`. However, I am at a loss as this solution differs from just adding them as the argument of `render()` as indicated in [the reference in R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html). Does anyone else get these errors? Would anyone know if there is a way to avoid creating a global `params` object?

```
number <- c(100, 200, 300)
for(i in 1:3){
params =  list(
      doc_title = paste("Some_title"),
      date = lubridate::today(),
      site_number = number[i]
  )
print(params)
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "work_formatting.Rmd",
  output_file = paste0("word_formatting_", number[i], ".docx"), 
  output_format = my_word(),
  params = params,
  clean = TRUE,
  quiet = FALSE
)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameters need to be pre-defined (with or without default values) in the yaml header.

````
---
params:
  doc_title:
  date:
  site_number:
title: "`r params$doc_title`"
author: "Paul M. Hargarten"
---
 

Date Generated: `r params$date`

# Header 1

Blah blah blah text

```{r cars}
cat("For site ", params$site_number, "\n")
summary(cars)
```
````

```r
rmarkdown::render(
  "69831130.Rmd",
  params = list(doc_title="hello", date=Sys.Date(), site_number=111L)
)
```

[image: rendering of rmarkdown document]

Comment: Thank you, r2evans. I want to pass the parameters as an argument in `render()` instead of specifying them in the YAML header.  I'm trying to figure out this quote from cited reference: "If both the YAML field and the argument are present, the parameter values in the argument will override the corresponding parameters in YAML." This seems to imply that I shouldn't have YAML parameters. So, I am confused; are you saying that I still need to specify the parameters in the YAML header as shown?

Comment: So you're saying that only those parameters are passed to the doc that have default values defined in the header? When was this change introduced? I don't think rmarkdown worked this way one year ago.

Comment: @lith If you try to do this with the above doc and `rmarkdown::render(..., params=list(site_number=1, quux=2))` then it fails with the message `Error: render params not declared in YAML: quux`. I think that fairly definitive, not sure if/when that behavior changed.

Comment: @phargart, to answer your question ... anything listed in the `params=` argument *must* be defined in the yaml header of the rmarkdown document. Not everything in the yaml header needs to be included in the `params=` argument. It should be clear from my answer that I predefine empty variables; if it's not immediately obvious that they must be predefined in the yaml header, it should become so when one tries to remove one and rerender, giving errors.